# Photoshop: using the Pen tool for straight lines

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, pen-tool

When I use my pen tool I can add a curve lines, but I am unable to get a straight line after that.

In illustrator I just click the anchor point after the curve to then go straight, but on my windows computer I can not figure out how to do that in photoshop.

Answer (score 4):

For the standard **Pen Tool** — After pulling a curve, hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and **click the last anchor**. This breaks the anchor's symmetry. You can then click to create a straight segment, or click-drag to create an un-smooth curve. This is the same functionality as Illustrator only you *must* hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key for the click.

For the **Freeform Pen Tool** — After dragging to create curved paths, hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and release the "click". You will see the straight segment. You can then click again, release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, and continue to draw curved segments.

More detailed info [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/drawing-pen-tools.html) — see section called "Draw curves followed by straight lines".

Answer (score 0):

For creating horizontal and vertical straight lines you can click for first point then press **Shift** and click for the second point (you need to be close to horizontal or vertical to succeed)

Comment: I believe this is for *brushes* not the *pen tools*.

Comment: @Scott, I test it in Photoshop and it give me the expected result. I use pen and do not drag, just click

Comment: `Shift` with the **Pen Tool** will constrain paths to 90 or 45 degree angles. Yes those will be straight path segments, but without `Shift` you can merely click **anywhere** and the result will be a straight path. `Shift` is not necessary for merely straight path segments if you click rather than click-drag. It's a subtle difference, but a difference nonetheless. You really don't need the `Shift` key unless you *want* a 90 or 45 degree path.